# Spring Data Query Spits out exceptions and i cant fix it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am having a problem with spring in which i can't seem to find a way to put it to compile.
My project is a mix between java and kotlin.
Here i show my query:

```
@Query("select u from users u inner join fetch u.subjects where ?1 member of u.subjects")
fun findBySubjectInSubjects(subject: SubjectDAO) : List<ProfessorDAO>
```

Now i'll show the actual relations in the entities beacuse even though i think they're right,  doubt everything right now

in the ProfessorDAO.class

```
@ManyToMany
private Set<SubjectDAO> subjects;
```

in the SubjectDAO.class

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = ProfessorDAO.class, mappedBy = "subjects")
private Set<ProfessorDAO> professors;
```

Why doesn't the query compile? Ive tried multiple things and it never does. It spits out exceptions saying that cant validate the query. I tried without the join, without the select, with "in" instead of "member of" and im out of ideias. I must recognize im a bit of a noob on spring since i just started learning for a college subject.

Comment: I don't think you need that `@Query` at all; Spring Data should be able to autogenerate it.

Comment: I tried that, and agree with you from what i saw in the documentation. But it says property SubjectInSubjects can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for this method:

```
fun findBySubjects(subject: SubjectDAO) : List<ProfessorDAO>
```

It returns returns all of the professors who have the given subject in their subjects collection.

Answer (score 0):

Select u.* From users u. 
Try astrik mark.